# make server side jquery searching using jquery.select2.js

Tags: jquery

how to use severside side search in drop dowm my code is here

the data in drop down come from database ....
any help please ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({

                ajax: {
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/getdatabyajax2",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250
                }
            })

        });

    </script>
    <h4 class="label">Filter Data By Name </h4>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" id="nme" name="name">

        <?php foreach($groups1 as $name){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $name->emp_id; ?>"><?php echo $name->Name; ?></option>;
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: please send me the link of those answere which is related to this question

Comment: when we give url like it goes direct to fuction so what we include in the function